# PHP Missing Extension "mcrypt" in Joomla

Tags: extension, joomla, php, missing

In my panel civicrm display mistake: "PHP Missing Extension "mcrypt". I am add screen with this post. In screen show this mistake.
Pleas help me to fix this bug.
[image]

PHP Missing Extension mcrypt joomla

Comment: have you read the other posts about mcrypt?

Comment: I can not search post about mcrypt and Joomla

Comment: If you can't search, note that in the right sidebar here there are some automatic suggestions that appear. One of them is this link https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25769/what-to-do-with-mcrypt-message-after-upgrading-to-php-7-2?rq=1

Comment: i don't see why you need to limit your search to just joomla

Comment: at least read the other mcrypt Questions, then update your Q to say what you have read/understood/tried

Comment: I am don't speak English, and this post for me don't understand, but now i am understand all information.
I installed php 7.1 and the system is now working as it should.
Thank you friend.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to do with "mcrypt" message after upgrading to PHP 7.2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/25769/what-to-do-with-mcrypt-message-after-upgrading-to-php-7-2)